How do i explain non significant effect of covariates in simple moderation analysis?
I am doing a simple moderation analysis with one independent variable (IV), one moderator (M), and one dependent variable (DV). The results found no significant interaction, meaning my M does not play a moderating role. I added covariates to see if it could change the interaction, but all of my covariates were also not significant and the interaction results remain the same. How do I explain this in my report? Please share if you similar results/papers that could give examples on this

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Report the result as is? The moderator does not moderate the effect of your predictor, regardless of whether covariates are controlled for or not. If you had a background theory about the moderation effect, you can say that your results did not support that theory, and discuss this in light of earlier findings related to the theory.
As a side note, putting in covariates after observing a non-desired result in the hope of getting the desired result is generally poor practice and undermines the reliability of significance testing.
